# UDP not dropping any packets

Tags: c#, c++, udp, winsock

I have a C# client and C++ server program that use UDP to communicate. For now i'm simply using 127.0.0.1 (localhost) to simulate the communication on one machine.

The problem is that no UDP packets were dropped my 10,000 packet test between the client and server on the same machine, so i don't know how to write the code for retransmission because i can't get it to drop a packet, but it will happen in a real scenario between a client and server on separate machines.

Is it not dropping any packets because the client and server are on the same machine?

Comment: Yes, it is. It's very hard to drop packets on a loopback connection.

Comment: `if(rand() < RAND_MAX/8) /* don't send the packet */ else {send(...)}`

Comment: Thanks guys. @immibis ah ok i was thinking i could do something like that thanks

Comment: Check out [clumsy](https://jagt.github.io/clumsy/), it sounds like it'll work for you.

Answer (score 1):

UDP does not usualy drops packet on same machine. Instead of using rand() function approach you can do another trick. Send large packets from the sender and receive in smaller chunks in the receiver code. And use sleep function after every receive. So one the pipe gets full, you may notice packet drops